# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ExpoWebView": following expo native module tutorial

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Very new to creating native views in react native. I'm following an expo guide here:
https://docs.expo.dev/modules/native-view-tutorial/

I already had an existing project so I deviated from it a bit. Instead of running `npx create-expo-module expo-web-view` as a stand alone module I went into my project directory and ran `npx create-expo-module@latest --local`.

This created a modules folder inside my existing project:
[image]

I replaced the files that the tutorial comments on and then went to run `npx expo prebuild`

Which led me to this error:
[image]

I need help figuring out what this means and where I should look next.

Comment: Could you share the podfile?, so it will be easier to investigate the issue.